# Extract image url associated to a category

Tags: categories, images

I found a function that allows me to attach a category to an image in media uploader

```
function add_categories_to_attachments() {
      register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );  
}  
add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

I'd like to be able to, when I'm in the category I assigned the image to, get the url of the image.

I just need to find out how to extract the info about the image associated with that category.

I should be able to do that via taxonomies, but I don't know how to achieve that.

EDIT: I forgot to add that I'm working outside of the loop, I need to show this image in the breadcrumbs of the category view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I needed:

```
$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;

$images = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'category__in' => $cat_id));

if ( !empty($images) ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        $image_url = $image->guid;
    }
} else{
    $image_url = '';
}
```

First I got the category, and current category ID I'm in. Then in `$images` I got the attachment that's attached to this category. Then I just listed them (I used `print_r` to see all the array values fro $images) and found the url (I need the url of the image to set the background image in the breadcrumbs). You can get the image directly by using `wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID)`, but I need the url so I'm using this.

Oh and I'm avoiding the plugin usage, since I'm building a theme, and I'd like everything to be available from the theme itself.

Hope this helps someone :)